# using different session model name in Authlogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I changed UserSession model name to Session in Authlogic gem but i'm getting this error.

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#new

undefined method `login_field' for Object:Class
```

Is it forbidden to use Session as a model name ?

db schema

```
 create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "crypted_password"
    t.string   "password_salt"
    t.string   "persistence_token"
    t.string   "perishable_token"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

sessions_controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @session = Session.new
  end

  def create
    @session = Session.new(params[:session])

      if @session.save
        redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Login successful.')
      else
        render :action => "new"

      end

  end

  def destroy
    @session = Session.find
    @session.destroy
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Goodbye!')
  end
end
```

model: session.rb

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base

end
```

application_controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery


 helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

    private
      def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
        @current_user_session = Session.find
      end

      def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
      end


end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@session) do |f| %>

  <% if @session.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error messages">
      <ul>
      <% @session.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :login %>
    <%= f.text_field :login %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
class Session < Authlogic::Session::Base
  authenticate_with User
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |configuration| 
    configuration.session_class = Session
  end
end
```

Comment: I had a "wrong constant name" error. It was fixed by the additions to the Session model. The User config was unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did not found the documentation for this any where :/